# Opening new window in Tkinter freezes the program (python 3.6)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have something like this:

first.py

```
from tkinter import *

def new_window(event):
    root.destroy()
    import second

root = Tk()
b = Button(root, text='New window')
b.pack()
b.bind('<Button-1>', new_window)
root.mainloop()
```

second.py

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

But when I open the second window, the first one is destroyed (I hope so), but the second one is frozen (it is shown, but there is no close-button on the top and I only see the launch-icon). Why is it so? Don't I kill the first loop?

Comment: describe it better

Comment: Welcome to [so]! +1 For asking a good question with a well written [mcve]! Easiest workaround would probably using OOP, as in instead of having your main script jump on other scripts, create classes in other scripts to have GUI-like objects and simply create & destroy them in your main-script. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/7032856) as a starting point perhaps, it really helped me very much.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely because `import second` never returns since the last thing it does is call `root.mainloop()`. Since it never returns, the callback in the first window never finishes. And since it never finishes, it's not able to process any other events.

Comment: so do i have to return something or...?

Comment: @R.Blackheart: I'm not sure what the solution is. This is not how tkinter was designed to be used.